# Due to Haproxy I didn't get the client ip address in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, haproxy

I am using Haproxy for load balancing.

My website run on ruby on rails.

I have done some googling and come to know to add this line

```
option forwardfor header X-Client
```

**in /etc/haproxy.cfg file.**

In my rails application I'm using

```
request.env["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]
```

but this give me my master application ip

How do I get client ip address.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the `option forwardfor` directive, you should also use `option http-server-close`. If you don't, HAProxy will only add the header to the initial request.

If you did that and restarted HAProxy, it should work.

Comment: I have add this but then also it didn't work. I have restarted HAProxy with this command haproxy -f /etc/haproxy.cfg -p /var/run/haproxy.pid -sf $(cat /var/run/haproxy.pid)

Answer (score 0):

Also I find it strange that your code relies on a variable name "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR" and that the header name would be X-Client. Please just use "option forwardfor" which will set the X-Forwarded-For header that I think your application is looking for.

Comment: I have set option forwardfor only but then also it didn't work for me :(

Comment: Then you have to take a network trace to pinpoint the location where it's missing, because everyone uses it with no issue, so it's necessarily dropped somewhere.